# How to get the time it took to connect on a request basis using Jetty Client

Tags: java, http, jetty, http2, jetty-9

I want to compute **per request** the time between the begining of request and time connection is established (TCP connection establishment).

I asked this question [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66605208/how-to-get-the-time-it-took-to-connect-using-jetty-client) but it was ambiguous.

I had a look at proposed answer, maybe I misunderstood, but I understand that Connection.Listener works on a global basis at least  (Overall connect time)

So I tried the approach based on SocketAddressResolver:

```
    private static class CustomSocketAddressResolver implements SocketAddressResolver {
        private StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
        
        private SocketAddressResolver adaptee;
        
        public CustomSocketAddressResolver(SocketAddressResolver adaptee) {
            this.adaptee = adaptee;
        }
        
        public long getConnectTime() {
            return stopWatch.getTime();
        }


        @Override
        public void resolve(String host, int port, Promise<List<InetSocketAddress>> promise) {
            stopWatch.reset();
            stopWatch.start();          
            adaptee.resolve(host, port, new Promise<List<InetSocketAddress>>() {

                @Override
                public void succeeded(List<InetSocketAddress> result) {
                    // Add as first address an invalid address so that we test
                    // that the connect operation iterates over the addresses.
                    stopWatch.stop();
                    promise.succeeded(result);
                }

                @Override
                public void failed(Throwable x) {
                    stopWatch.stop();
                    promise.failed(x);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Then I can get connect time like this:

```
 ((CustomSocketAddressResolver) httpClient.getSocketAddressResolver()).getConnectTime()
```

It works but is there a better way ?

Comment: What if it's taking less than 1ms - or if the clock precision is less than the time to connect? [back in Windows XP days you were lucky if you got 50-100ms precision].

Comment: Hello, what do you propose in this case ?

Comment: Well is it an issue if it's that small?  Are you optimising something that doesn't need optimising (see answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to compute per request the time between the begining of request and time connection is established (TCP connection establishment).

Perhaps there is a misunderstanding here.

HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2 use persistent TCP connections.
A TCP connection is created, kept open, and reused for many requests.

For example, a TCP connection is created and then reused for, say, 1067 requests, and then still kept open.

It would not make much sense to compute the time between the beginning of the 1067th request and the time the connection was first established (or I would love to hear a use case for that).

I know of case where connections remain open for days.

Comment: Hello, it would be for performance testing purpose. Yes I am aware of what you describe and the connect time would be 0 for the request made when connection are open for same VIrtual User. Does my code look correct for the purpose I describe ? Is there a better/easier way ? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Typically measuring connect time is irrelevant for most benchmark that are interested in request times. Just measure response times, see for example: https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-load-generator.

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointers. Is the approach described in question still valid (as per your other answer ? ) ?

Comment: The approach in the code snippet in your question is not thread safe.

Comment: Indeed, I don't think synchronizing StopWatch access is enough right as a call to resolve might be running for 1 threads while CustomSocketAddressResolver#getConnectTime is called for another one. Is there some kind of Context per request I could use to store this information per call ?

Comment: Don't use `StopWatch`, just use `System.nanoTime()`. However, consider that you probably don't need this at all for "performance testing purposes", so perhaps just drop it and concentrate on the interesting data only (the response times). The code snippet above is only measuring the DNS and TCP stack performance of the client, which has no relevance at the application level (it is what it is and you cannot change it).